# How do I see full movie titles in iPad Video browser?

Tags: ios, ipad

On my iPad, long video titles are cut off even though there is lots of blank space everywhere. Even when I tap a video, the detail screen cuts off the title in the exact same location despite there still being lots of blank space everywhere.

Full movie titles are a lot more useful than blank space... Can I somehow see them at all when I'm away from my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tap and hold, you will get a popover until you let go with the full details.  Same works with music in the ipod app.

Comment: I did this but it doesn't work. Tap what?

Comment: The movie title...

Comment: Doesn't work, all that does is bring up the delete "x" in the upper left corner, so frustrating! Am I missing something?